# Can we add page references to a page containing a certain sentence?

Tags: cross-referencing

The title basically says it all. As an example: I'm writing a conclusion and would like to refer to the page on which I wrote a discussion covering this part my conclusion in more detail. Unfortunately, this page does not contain floats or equations which I could reference and even then, it would only be workaround as changing things later on could move the float onto a different page than the discussion I want to refer to.

I know, text doesn't have counters but since I need just the page number, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Make a normal `\label` (inside the referenced paragraph or at its end) and then refer to it with `\pageref` to get the page number.

Comment: Thanks. Probably should have tested this before asking. Anyway, now it's here for others.

Comment: @PacificOrion It's a trick also used for finding out the total amount of pages. Place \label before \end{document} and pageref gives the number of pages.